# Hashing routine explanation

Tags: hashing

As the title states, I would like to know what a hashing routine is. I found online about hashing algorithms but I heard it, being used in a different context.

Comment: What context did you hear it in? How does it differ from what you've found online?

Comment: And does this answer your question? https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55471/what-exactly-and-precisely-is-hash?rq=1

Comment: start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function